# What is this formula representing?

Tags: organic-chemistry, identification

[image]

What is the formula on this cup representing?

Comment: It's caffeine, what else you'd expect?

Comment: You may "get it" even as a pendant (e.g., https://www.etsy.com/market/caffeine_pendant), albeit *some* representations appear, chemically speaking, questionable.

Answer (score 6):

It's a coffee mug, and coffee is (in)famous for one particular substance: [Caffeine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeine).

The 2D picture on Wikipedia is the same as on the mug, except that it's rotated 180 degrees. The 'sticks' are methyl ($\ce{CH3}$) groups.

[image]