# What molecule is this?

Tags: identification

I have tried some only searches but I couldn't find the molecule name. Can someone identify this for me?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this formula representing?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76012/what-is-this-formula-representing)

Answer (score 1):

This is [caffeine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeine).

By the way, you can draw structures in [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/) (or related websites) for somewhat simple structural identification.